# Proxy setting applies to internet browsing only ( on Galaxy S II )

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, proxy

I have done the setting for proxy server on my Galaxy S II. It works for internet browsing only. Other applications that use internet, do not work. Anyone has got that working?

Answer (score 2):

It's up to the app to fetch the [proxy settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Proxy.html) from the system prior to making the first connection. If a app does not do this and your local firewall prevents outgoing connections without the proxy, it will not work.

You should contact your *app developer* about this problem and ask him to fix this.